# Help! get node value via php simplexml !

Tags: php, simplexml

I just want to get the value from xml node.So I following the code from php document:
SimpleXMLElement::xpath() .But it didn't.And I thought the Xpath is much more inconvenience ，is there a much better way to get the node I want??!

my php code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @author kevien
 * @copyright 2010
 */

$arr = array ();

$xml = simplexml_load_file("users.xml");

$result = $xml->xpath('/users/user[@id="126"]/watchHistory/whMonthRecords[@month="2010-09"]/whDateList/date');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {

    array_push($arr, $node);
}

print_r($arr);
?>
```

it returns:

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 02 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 03 ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 06 ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 10 ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 21 ) )
```

my part of users.xml :

```
<users>
    <user id="126">
        <name>老黄牛三</name>
        <watchHistory>
            <whMonthRecords month="2010-09">
                <whDateList month="2010-09">
                    <date>02</date>
                    <date>03</date>
                    <date>06</date>
                    <date>10</date>
                    <date>21</date>
                </whDateList>
                      </<whMonthRecords>
               </<watchHistory>>
      </user>
  </users>
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your whole loop with:

```
foreach ($result as $node) {
    $arr[] = (string)$node;
}
```

or even:

```
$result = array_map('strval', $result);
```